# How to send c++ doubles from one system to another Sender: Winsock Receiver: Java

Tags: java, c, network-programming, double, htonl

The sending C-side

```
double tmp = htonl(anydouble);
send(socket, (char *) &tmp, sizeof(tmp), 0);
```

On the Java side, im reading the network data into a char[8]

What is the proper way of performing the conversion back to double?
Is it the way to go to simply send a string and parse it back to double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice to use Google Protocol Buffers: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview It has libs for C and Java and many other languages, like for example Python, which you may find useful later. It is efficient, robust, will take care of endianness, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
char[] sentDouble = readBytes(); // get your bytes char[8]
String asString = new String(sentDouble); // make a string out of it
double myDouble = Double.parseDouble(asString); // parse it into a double
```

With a byte[] you can do

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public static double toDouble(byte[] bytes) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getDouble();
}
```

Comment: This is pseudo code obviously. I don't have a `readbytes()` method. `Doube.parseDouble()` throws exception, catch it.

Comment: This would probably work if i sent the double in a human readable form as a string, but not sending the "plain" 64Bit.

Comment: A Double is 8 bytes, so you would need byte[8] or char[4]. With byte[8] you can use what I edited in my answer.

Comment: +1 for a non-String solution that doesn't reinvent the wheel like I just did.

Comment: With the ByteBuffer you need to make sure you match the byte order used for sending the double or make sure the server sends it in network byte order.

Comment: You would need that for char[] as well. So, yes, order and size of sent and received must match.

Answer (score 1):

You're reinterpreting a double as a long. This won't be portable. Here are some alternatives:

- do you really need to use floating point values? Can you represent your values as integers (e.g. milliseconds instead of seconds)?
- encode the double as a string (e.g. sprintf and Double.parseDouble)
- extract mantissa and exponent with frexp and send as integers, then convert back in Java with Double.longBitsToDouble

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for `String` overhead.  Assemble the bytes into a `long` first, then use [Double's static longBitsToDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) method.

```
// The bit pattern for the double "1.0", assuming most signficant bit first in array.
char[] charArray = new char[] {0x3F, 0xF0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
long bytesAsLong = 0L;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
   bytesAsLong |= ((long) charArray[i] << (56 - 8*i));
}
double value = Double.longBitsToDouble(bytesAsLong);
System.out.println(value);  // prints "1.0"
```